# Using Inductor and Electronic Load Instead of a Permanent Magnet Synchronous Motor (PMSM)

Tags: power, motor, power-electronics, test-equipment, electronic-load

I would like to test whether my power board can handle to currents required to drive a 1.5 kW motor. My issue is that the motor testbench is still not here and I have to test it now.

I do not have high power resistors at hand. What I do have, are some 30-40 uH high current inductors and electronic loads. My question is: Do you think it is a good idea if I simulate the motor's phases with an inductor (simulating the winding of the motor) and an electronic load (simulating the EMF)?

Any other ideas are also highly appreciated!

Comment: frankly I don't think it would work. The PMSM control needs also to determine the rotor angle with any known methods.

Comment: @MarkoBuršič I think the control will be OK, as I also can just control it in open loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Electronic loads are non-linear and contain capacitors. They would not make good test loads. There is probably a way to control the power board that would allow limited testing with inductive loads. You may be able to program some fixed switching sequences.

You should also see if you could find some heating appliances that you could use for resistive loads. If you can find enough incandescent bulbs, they might work. The test load should have the same impedance for each phase. You might be able to construct resistors with pieces of stainless steel.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer! I was afraid exactly of what you also said. Incandescent bulbs is a very good idea I didn't think about. However, I have to check if I have them at proper voltage rating. Now I am also thinking of using only inductors. Even though real power will not be consumed, the same current through the phases can flow, and this is what stresses the MOSFETs the most.

Comment: Using only inductors will cause higher than normal current in the inverse parallel diodes and higher than normal ripple current in the DC bus capacitors.

Comment: For the DC bus capacitors I agree, and this will not be a problem in my case. For the parallel diodes I am not sure why would higher current flow there. May you explain? I thought that in inverter design usually no current flows through the body diodes, and that the switch is closed whenever current wants to flow through it.

Comment: An inverter with an inductive load must allow current to flow in the direction that opposes the supply voltage. That is the nature of current without power transfer. There is equal power transfer in both directions. I have read that MOSFETs handle that in a different way, but I don't understand it. Whatever the details are, a highly inductive load will stress that mechanism more than a load with moderate inductance.